# Can a Typescript decorator get access to DEFAULT arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to intercept default arguments in my decorator,
but they come up empty. Executing the function with actual parameters works but I can't get access to the defaults. Why?

I can't find this anywhere and seems like it should be very basic.

Here are is the decorated function

```
  @multiplyBy2('multiplying by 2')
  test(num: number  = 5, anotherNum: number = 3, trash = 'garbage') {
   return num * anotherNum; 
  }
```

And here is the decorator

```
export function multiplyBy2 (message: any): any {

    return function(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){

      const originalFunction = descriptor.value;

      descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        console.log('The arguments: ', args);

        let answer = originalFunction.apply(this, args)

        return answer * 2
     }
   }
}
```

Below are just the pictures of the code.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/

Comment: @JörgWMittag Done

Comment: I’m not super familiar with decorators, but I expect the answer will be that you can’t, because parameter defaults in JavaScript are expressions evaluated at call time. For example, you can write things like `(a, b = 2 * a) => a + b`.

Comment: Thanks @Ry. I would think though that being if you are able to get the result, logically you would be able to get the parameters that led to the result

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to get the function as a string and parse out the formal params and analyze there.